# Can't get list Objects from Localstack s3 bucket using php aws S3Client

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk, localstack

I have aws s3 localstack in docker-compose declared as:

```
version: "3"

services:
...
 localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - USE_SSL=false
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    ports:
      - "4572:4572"
      - "4566:4566"
      - "8083:8080"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

After build everything works fine. I am able to connect to the image:

```
docker exec -ti my-project_localstack_1 /bin/bash
```

And make a new bucket using command line:

```
awslocal s3 mb s3://my-bucket
```

Initially I was able to put new objects into the bucket from my php app.
But was not able to see/view list of them from php/postman/browser.

I've made some research and found [this](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/406#issuecomment-498309348) solution.

```
awslocal s3 mb s3://my-bucket

awslocal s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket my-bucket --acl public-read
```

Now, I am able to get list of objects by prefix in anonymous mode (no credentials or tokens) in my Chrome browser and using Postman.

But I fail to get `$s3Client->listObjects(...)`. It always returns empty result.

Note: I am still able to execute `$s3Client->putObject(...)`.
And I checked another commands `$s3client->getBucketAcl(...)` and `$s3Client->getObjectUrl(...)`. They work fine. 
What I want to say, connection to the localstack host from php is fine and instance is working and responding fine.

Here is the code on php side that I use to instantiate `$s3Client`:

```
class S3
{
    /** @var \Aws\S3\S3Client  */
    private static $client = null;
    private static function init()  // Lazy S3client initiation
    {
        if (is_null (self::$client)) {
            self::$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client ([
                'region'  => 'us-east-1',
                'version' => '2006-03-01',
                'credentials'   => false,
                'endpoint' => "http://localstack:4572",
                'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
                'debug' => true
            ]);
        }
    }  
    ...
    public static function list_objects($bucket, array $options)
    {
        self::init();

        return self::$client->listObjects([
            'Bucket'    => "my-bucket",
            'Prefix'    => "year/month/folder/",
            'Delimiter' => $options['delimiter'] ? $options['delimiter'] : '/',
        ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

This method returns `@metadata->effectiveUri` :

```
 array (size=2)
    'instance' => string '0000000040d78e4d00000000084dbdb3' (length=32)
    'data' => 
      array (size=1)
        '@metadata' => 
          array (size=4)
            'statusCode' => int 200
            'effectiveUri' => string 'http://localstack:4572/my-bucket?prefix=year%2Fmonth%2Ffolder%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url'
```

If I take this url and run it in **browser** or **postman** or php docker terminal **curl** it returns list of my files. It only returns empty array when I call it though s3Client in php.

I have a feeling that something is wrong with permissions. But since I don't have that much knowledge and experience with aws-s3 service I can't figure that out. And it seem confusing that some "default" permissions allows client to put objects but restrict to read index. And I can read index of objects using browser or curl, but not through the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encounted the same problem.
However, I changed the docker-compose as follows, then I could avoid the problem.

`image: localstack/localstack:0.11.0`

I think it may be a degradation issue of localstack.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But I am still confused why it worked for curl and browser but not for php client.

Comment: Thanks to create issue https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2535 .

Comment: Are you from localstack team?

Comment: No, I am a freelance IT engineer.

Comment: I'm getting this same behaviour on 0.11.5 and 0.11.6, it looks as though the 0.12.* release has fixed this

Comment: Scratch that, I'm getting really varied results in the 0.12.* release, I'd stick with 0.11.0 for now